# How to query with CAML?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development

I have a list called `employees` and it has a column named `Birthday`. I have to campare if today is birthday,

how can I query in this way:

```
 DateTime Date = DateTime.Now;

 SPQuery = new SPQuery();
 query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Ditlindja' />" + "<Value Type='DateTime'>" + date + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

this code is not working with string type it works but not with DateTime why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below query to compare birthday with current date.

```
SPQuery = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Ditlindja' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value></Eq></Where>";
```

**By using variable**

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

     SPQuery = new SPQuery();
     query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Ditlindja' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + date + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: yes this works but i need to make it with local variable

Comment: Check updated answer.... If it is not working than you need to convert your ate with utc..

Comment: no it is not working with variable

Comment: Have you tried to convert it to UTC or in ISO format?